# Differentiate between two pack expansions

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Is there a way to explicitly specify which `...` refers to which pack expansion? In my code I have two pack expansions that I want to apply at different levels:

```
template<typename T, int N>
struct MyArr
{
    T e[N];

    constexpr T& operator[](int i) { return e[i]; }
    constexpr const T& operator[](int i) const { return e[i]; }

    MyArr() : e{} {}
    template<typename ...type_pack>
    MyArr(const type_pack&... pack) : e{pack...}
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(pack)==N, 
        "Argument count must match the size.");
    }
};

template<typename type_lhs, typename type_rhs>
auto add(const type_lhs& lhs, const type_rhs& rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}

template<int ...I, typename type_head, typename ...type_pack, int N, typename Function>
auto apply(Function&& op, 
const MyArr<type_head,N>& head, const MyArr<type_pack,N>&... pack)
{
    return MyArr<type_head,N>((op(head[I],(pack[I])...))...);
    //                              expand pack[I]- ^ ,  ^ - expand I...
};

int main()
{
    MyArr<int,3> a(1,2,3);
    return apply<0,1,2>(add<int,int>, a, a);
}
```

Essentially, I want to get:

```
(op(head[0], get<0>(pack)[0], ..., get<M-1>(pack)[0]),
 ..., 
 op(head[N-1], get<0>(pack)[N-1], ..., get<M-1>(pack)[N-1]))
```

Thanks to OznOg's advice I got it to work through creating a function in the middle:

```cpp
template<int ...I, typename type_head, typename ...type_pack, int N, typename Function>
auto apply(Function&& op, 
const MyArr<type_head,N>& head, const MyArr<type_pack,N>&... pack)
{
    auto op2 = [&](int i) { return op(head[i], pack[i]...);};
    return MyArr<type_head,N>(op2(I)...);
};
```

Comment: your op takes 2 args isn't it? how do you expect it to work?

Comment: @OznOg It should return `MyArr<int, 3>(add(a[0],a[0]), add(a[1],a[1]), add(a[2],a[2]))` in this specific case. See my comment at the end about what kind of expansion I am expecting. I am unsure whether C++ allows mixing two expansions, and if it does, how do I indicate which expansion is for `I` and which for `pack`? Note the two `...` here: `(op(head[I],(pack[I])...))...`.

Comment: it allows mixing packed but expect them to be the same size

Comment: @OznOg Is there a link/reference I could refer to regarding this?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack "If the names of two parameter packs appear in the same pattern, they are expanded simultaneously, and they must have the same length: "

Comment: @OznOg I assume this means that this is impossible with the current features of C++. Namely I do not want those to get expanded simultaneously - one is nested inside the other, and clearly I want to allow for a different expansion size for both. You could formulate this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: I think you need an intermediate function and you should use make_integer_sequence with your N

Comment: @OznOg See the edit. I believe this is what you meant. Thank you for showing me the correct direction to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, the only way I see is the use of an helper function (`getVal()`, in the following example)

```
template <int I, typename type_head, typename ...type_pack, int N,
          typename Function>
auto getVal (Function&& op, MyArr<type_head,N> const & head,
             MyArr<type_pack,N> const & ... pack)
 { return op(head[I], pack[I]...); }

template <int ... Is, typename type_head, typename ...type_pack, int N,
          typename Function>
auto apply (Function && op, MyArr<type_head,N> const & head,
            MyArr<type_pack,N> const &... pack)
 { return MyArr<type_head,N>{ getVal<Is>(op, head, pack...)... }; }
```

The problem is that you have

```
(pack[I])...
```

so there is no way (as far I know) to say that the expansion is to be applied to `pack` and not to `I`.

With the intermediate function

```
//.......................VVV  expand pack
getVal<Is>(op, head, pack...)...
//...........................^^^  expand Is
```

you can use parentheses to separate the levels.

But you have to separate `pack` and `Is`.

Comment: Am I correctly understanding, that this: `getVal<Is>(op, head, pack...)...` is being evaluated as a nested expression? That is, first pack is expanded inside `getVal<Is>`, then `getVal<Is>` is expanded with respect to `Is`. Additionally how does this compare to what I came up with the lambda function? Is any of these supposed to be more performant, or will both result in a similar codegen (this matters as I will use this in computation heavy parts of my code).

Comment: @lightxbulb - Yes, it seems to me that you have correctly understand: the first ellipsis expand `pack` inside the `getVal()` call; the second ellipsis expand `Is` multiplying the `getVal()` calls. About the lambda function... conceptually I don't see great differences. From the point of view of performances... frankly I don't know.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply, it's much appreciated.